# How to create an ERD using phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, erd

is it possible to create an ERD using phpmyadmin?

I see people posting the following link : http://goo.gl/0z3vFE

But this does not work for me, for some reason I don't have that option in the 'MORE' menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin version > 3.4 ?

Comment: Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPYLbaXa35o seems that you would have to change a bit the config.

Comment: I've tried to alter the things like described in the following link; http://neeocis.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/phpmyadmin-how-to-enable-designer-in-phpmyadmin/ . but didn't work

Comment: logut and login again then, that should do.

Comment: It should. But the menu is still the same..

Comment: detail blog: http://sforsuresh.in/generating-erd-using-phpmyadmin-4

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might be using phmpmyadmin of (MAMP/WAMP/XAMP), for these there is no options for more, see here in more details,
Here are the steps which I used to preferred to generate ERD of DB-

1. Go to your PHPMyAdmin setup, usually it is `“http://localhost/phpmyadmin”` in your local machine. (if using mamp it would be `http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/`)
2. Select the **database for which you want** to generate.
3. Select **“Designer”** from last menu item of more section i.e.
   [image]

   **(OR)**
   if you are using (MAMP/WAMP/XAMP Phmpmyadmin) then-
   [image]
4. You will land on page with different options to create ERD.
   [image]
5. Once you are done with ERD creation click on **“Export Schema**" (MAMP/WAMP/XAMP) coordinates for PDF schema.
   [image]
   **(OR)** click on “Import/Export coordinates for PDF schema” icon which is second last in phpmyadmin.

*Hope it will work !!!*

Comment: Do you have to manually create the ERD or is it possible to automatically export the diagram from the existing schema?

Comment: It will do that automatically, using schema. Just we have to go and click the "Export Schema".

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are doing this on a shared hosting. You won't find the more option on shared hosting. You can create a local version of your database and use the local phpmyadmin to generate the ERD.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of how to do this?

Comment: Login to your cpanel. Go to phpmyadmin. click on your database of choice. click export . The SQL dump file will be downloaded.Go to your local machine. Open your phpmyadmin. create a new database with exactly the same name as the database you exported. Open the newly created database and import the SQL dump.

Comment: I landed here while looking this up for an old client... I can confirm that I was able to find + open the designer in phpMyAdmin as launched from cPanel on their shared web host (crocweb). I was able to generate an E-R diagram. I would imagine the features available likely have a lot to do with how old the host's cPanel + phpMyAdmin versions are, and of course on the host's configuration.

Comment: You are right. I guess the feature must have been added now. As at 5yrs ago, it was not available.