# Generating ERD/Database schema using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have database in phpmyadmin , just i want to create the ERD/Database schema for that database . it is possible to create DB schema in phpmyadmin. i don't want use mysql workbench. i tried following link but doesn't work.

[it gives information how to ERD in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650671/how-to-create-an-erd-using-phpmyadmin)

this above link told me to upgrade the phpmyadmin version, must be than more 3.4

Answer (score 0):

yes we can make ERD in phpmyamin just need to upgrade the phpmyadmin version, i just update the phpmyadmin version to 4.3.9. then new Desinger menu appear in top after trigger. after this just select the database and click on designer tab.

following link for how to upgrade the version of phpmyadmin
[upgrade the phpmyadmin version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7QoGAYMeoI)

and second link for how to relation between tables

[Relation between table in phpmyadmin for making ERD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPYLbaXa35o)